# Predicate on DataView Constructor?

Tags: .net, datatable, predicate, dataview

I know this may sound crazy, but I swear that on two separate ocassions via intellisense I've seen an overload for the DataView constructor that took in a DataTable and either Predicate or Func, I don't remember what T was, either DataRow or DataRowView. But now I can't find it. It also took in another parameter, I want to say it was a Comparison, but I'm less about that fact. The problem is, I can no longer find that overload.

Looking at the definition, I see that there is only 3 constructors for DataView. I specifically remember that in intellisense for this "disappearing constructor" said "4 of 4".

Can someone please help me solve this mystery? Please tell me that I'm not delusional and did in fact see this constructor (or something like it). Maybe it wasn't actually a constructor and was an extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five constructors, but two of them (including one taking a predicate and a comparison) are internal to the `System.Data` assembly. I don't know why Intellisense would show that to you though...

Comment: Yep, I just found the same thing, I was about to post about it. I'm guessing is was some sort of random bug with intellisense. Damn. I wish it was public. I am glad to find that I'm not crazy though.

Comment: Something must be wrong with my VS install, because I just had the same problem happen again, except this time intellisense was showing me an internal constructor for CollectionView

internal CollectionView(IEnumerable collection, bool shouldProcessCollectionChanged);

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - unfortunately there are only 3 **public** constructors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.dataview.aspx